# Не обновляется изображение на странице, после загрузки на сервер?

Tags: php, изображения

Добрый день с названием темы может быть ошибка, но все равно жду помощи.
Есть страница. На ней аватар. При нажатии на который появляется форма для его изменения. Далее идет загрузка через `ajax` и отображение нового аватара ну и т.д.

Собственно в чем проблема? Когда я гружу все время разного расширения файлы `jpg, png, jpg, png`, изображение, перед закрытием формы выводится верно. Но если грузить подряд файлы одного расширения `.jpg, .jpg ...`. То всегда отображается старый аватар. Хотя в папке он сменился уже и при закрытии формы отображается так же верно.
Как я понимаю это связано с сохраненым изображением в кэше браузера?
Подскажите как можно это исправить?

Comment: можно попробовать, в конце всех манипуляций связанных с аякс загрузкой , сделать 
window.location.reload();

Comment: или давать каждому новому файлу новое имя
Проверьте, если после ctrl+f5 в браузере ошибка осталась, значит дело НЕ в кэше.

Comment: window.location.reload() - я не могу использовать, так как форма отображается js, и в вашем случае произойдет перезагрузка полностью страницы.
Новые имена - это хороший выход, но только? сколько же лишних файлов будет скапливаться. И придется писать какой нибудь уборщик.